# What does this rails task ‘rails active_storage:update’ do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-activestorage

Since rails 6, it seems we can update active_record configuration with this command `rails active_storage:update`.
Does anyone can explain what this task do exactly and why it has been introduced ?

Comment: It updates some column names on the polymorphic table responsible to manage the storage. I think. I did a task about it when I need to update from rails 6.0.X to a rails 6.1.

Comment: @PauloFelipeSouza do you know if there is any documentation talking about it in more detail?